# SinePWM - Modulation Index calculation for a 3phase igbt inverter with ac load

Tags: pwm, inverter

For a project I have to create a simulation of a 3 phase IGBT inverter with SinePWM (in Plecs) with a AC load

`Udc = 650V; cos(phi) = -1; I_ph = 500A; Uun/Uvn/Uwn = 230V;`

So I calculate my SinePWM modulation index like this `2*230V*sqrt(2) / Udc` whitch should be like 1.0008 a little bit overmodulation. Is that right?

Someone in my group noted that we have to use sqrt(3) aswell as its a 3 phase system and wants to multiply it so we get like 1.73 wich is waaaay to overmodulated.

Thanks!

Comment: So if the project is a simulation, why not simulate and find out yourself. On the available info in your question, it cannot be answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The modulation index is something you impose, yourself. What you're calculating is the maximum (peak) value of the sine for a 100% modulation. For example, if  `m=0.9` (90% modulation) then for your `Udc = 650 V` the peak sine would be `m*650 = 585 V`. You have a 3-phase application, so the phase to phase (LL) RMS value will be `m*650/sqrt(2) = 413.7 V`, and for the phase to ground (LN) the RMS will be `m*650/sqrt(6) = 238.8V`.

Comment: I see. But in the task the modulation factor is not given. Only the parameters I said are given and the tutor said we should calculate the modulation factor based on the give parameters i.e Udc/ I_pn and U_ph... So if get this right the overall task is just badly designed as a real example ?

Comment: @DanielDo Just extract \$m\$ from the formula above: \$m\cdot U_{DC}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}=V_{LL_{RMS}}\$. The same for \$V_{LN_{RMS}}\$, but with \$\sqrt{6}\$.

Answer (score 0):

The modulation index of 1.0008 is correct. The formulas posted above as an answer are incorrect.

The Phase-Neutral RMS voltage would be `V_an_rms = 1/sqrt(2) *ma*Vdc/2`.

Reason: The maximum peak voltage is always measured to a "virtual" neutral point of the DC link capacitor split in half.
E.g. the maximum peak voltage (with mi = 1.0 - no overmodulation) is `V_an_pk = Vdc / 2`.
From this value you can calculate RMS Line-Neutral voltage easily.

Line-to-Line rms voltage is then `V_LL_rms = sqrt(3) * V_an_rms`

E.g. `V_LL_rms = sqrt(3) / (2*sqrt(2)) * ma*Vdc`

(compare to Ned Mohan Power Electronics 2nd edition formula 8-57)